# beamer: How to get height for frame content

Tags: beamer, lengths, height

I want to put a picture in a beamer slide and make it use all the available height of the frame. So I tried:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{FRAMETITLE}
   \centering
    \includegraphics[height=\paperheight,draft]{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

but this makes my figure exceed the slide:

[image]

I guess `\paperheight` includes the frame title, hence it is too large. Is there something like a `\frameheight` length which corresponds to the exact height available for the frame's content?

Comment: Are you looking for `\textheight`?

Comment: No, I tried this as well and is has the same effect as `\paperheight`.

Comment: OK, can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: I updated the question ...

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262815/automatically-fit-the-graphics-in-the-remaining-space-of-a-beamer-slide can help

Comment: or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44218/set-image-to-full-all-available-space-in-beamer-without-overlapping-other-eleme

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Code basically taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/278434/36296 (=> Community Wiki answer)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\begin{frame}{Frametitle}
    \global\beamer@shrinktrue
    \gdef\beamer@shrinkframebox{
        \setbox\beamer@framebox=\vbox to\beamer@frametextheight{
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=\beamer@frametextheight]{example-image}
        }
    }
\end{frame}
\makeatother


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't this an overkill? Better solution, anyone?

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "overkill" and what should a "better" solution look like?

Comment: I'm not OP, but I was hoping for a solution akin to `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{path_to_figure.png}`, but with something like `height=\frameheight`.

Comment: All this other stuff (global, beamer, shrinkframebox, etc.) seems like overkill to me