# Minipage with image on one side, bullet points on other, With bullet points alligned at top and image centered

Tags: beamer

I have

```
\begin{frame}{Motivation}
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Dosimetry.png}
\end{figure} 
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\item 4
\item 5
\item 6
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
```

This positions the image on the left in the center as I desire, however it lines the first bullet points with the top of the image, whereas I want it at the top of the frame.

If I change the second begin minipage to to be `\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}` the bullet points get closer to be properly aligned, but the image moves down away from the center.

If in addition I change the first minipage to be `\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}` the bullet points are aligned correctly, however now the image is even further misaligned.

How can I have it so that the image is in the position it places with the original code shown, and the bullet points are in the position it places it with the original code changed to `\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth} and \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}`? I do not understand why this should be difficult.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Beamer centres the contents on one frame vertically, that's why the placement seems difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This is just a hack, for a sophisticated solution please see  [Skillmon's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383020/36296)

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Motivation}
    \begin{columns}[T]
        \begin{column}{0.57\textwidth}
            \vskip1.4cm
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.37\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item 1
                \item 2
                \item 3
                \item 4
                \item 5
                \item 6
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help, this does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 8):

Is this the desired output:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Motivation}
    \begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
        \vbox to \textheight{
            \vfill
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image}
            \vfill
        }
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
        \vbox to \textheight{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item 1
                \item 2
                \item 3
                \item 4
                \item 5
                \item 6
            \end{itemize}
            \vfill
        }
    \end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You could achieve the more or less same with the optional arguments of `minipage`:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Motivation}
    \begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][c]{0.6\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][t]{0.4\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item 1
                \item 2
                \item 3
                \item 4
                \item 5
                \item 6
            \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To get better results of vertical placement, one could use the code provided in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44298/117050) to calculate the `\contentheight` which is the height of the frame without the title and stuff.

With this we could further automate the process (note that `0.95\contentheight` gives better vertical centering of the image):

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\newif\ifsidebartheme
\sidebarthemefalse

\newdimen\contentheight
\newdimen\contentwidth
\newdimen\contentleft
\newdimen\contentbottom
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\calculatespace}{%
    \contentheight=\paperheight%
    \ifx\beamer@frametitle\@empty%
        \setbox\@tempboxa=\box\voidb@x%
      \else%
        \setbox\@tempboxa=\vbox{%
          \vbox{}%
          {\parskip0pt\usebeamertemplate***{frametitle}}%
        }%
        \ifsidebartheme%
          \advance\contentheight by-1em%
        \fi%
      \fi%
    \advance\contentheight by-\ht\@tempboxa%
    \advance\contentheight by-\dp\@tempboxa%
    \advance\contentheight by-\beamer@frametopskip%
    \ifbeamer@plainframe%
    \contentbottom=0pt%
    \else%
    \advance\contentheight by-\headheight%
    \advance\contentheight by\headdp%
    \advance\contentheight by-\footheight%
    \advance\contentheight by4pt%
    \contentbottom=\footheight%
    \advance\contentbottom by-4pt%
    \fi%
    \contentwidth=\paperwidth%
    \ifbeamer@plainframe%
    \contentleft=0pt%
    \else%
    \advance\contentwidth by-\beamer@rightsidebar%
    \advance\contentwidth by-\beamer@leftsidebar\relax%
    \contentleft=\beamer@leftsidebar%
    \fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \calculatespace%
    \begin{minipage}[c][0.95\contentheight][c]{0.6\textwidth}%
            \centering%
            \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image}%
    \end{minipage}\hfill%
    \begin{minipage}[c][0.95\contentheight][t]{0.4\textwidth}%
            \begin{itemize}%
                \item 1%
                \item 2%
                \item 3%
                \item 4%
                \item 5%
                \item 6%
            \end{itemize}%
    \end{minipage}%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this produces exactly what I want,thank you for your time and help. I'm sorry that I can't accept two answers.

Comment: @Jack then you should not use samcarters, imho. It uses a `\vskip` which you would have to adjust manually, mine seems more automated to me.

Comment: `\textheight` is probably a bit too height for the minipages, as this does not take into account the space for the frametitle. Maybe `.9\textheight` would give a better alignment.

Comment: @samcarter you're right. I didn't consider the title. Sorry for bashing your answer but the need for a manual `\vskip` just doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: @Skillmon Please don't apologize, in principle I find your approach better - however a fully automatic solution would have to measure the height of the frametitle - without that I don't see much difference in manually guessing the `textheight` or shifting the image with `vskip`.

Comment: @samcarter yes it would. Any idea how to do that? Last resort could be `\pdfsavepos` but I don't know how to use it correctly, and am afraid this might be overkill.

Comment: @Skillmon There are some hacky ways, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/368718/36296

Comment: @Skillmon https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44298/36296 sounds like a clean way to calculate the space.