# Is \textheight in beamer slides with a title wrong?

Tags: beamer, dimensions, height

The problem I have is simple to describe: the height of a beamer slide title does not seem to be subtracted from `\textheight`, leaving me with no idea how much space is left for the actual content.

A quick example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red] (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,\textheight);
\draw[blue] (0,\textheight) -- (\textwidth,0)
            (0,0) -- (\textwidth, \textheight);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Compiled with <code>pdflatex</code>]

So, is this a bug, or am I using it wrong or misunderstanding it? How would I go on about with drawing the above rectangle with the correct height?

Comment: This is correct, text height and width does not really have the same interpretation in beamer as in a normal document.

Comment: Hmm, after some tests in beamer, it seems `\textheight` is a lot taller inside tikzpicture than it is on the beamer frame. No idea why

Comment: Here is an exercise: `\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\draw[red] (current page.south west) 
  rectangle (\textwidth,0.3\textheight);\end{tikzpicture}`. Why do I need such a small height for the rectangle for the square to be seen.

Comment: related discussion about textheight: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383020/36296

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278429/is-there-a-simple-command-for-the-available-height-in-a-beamer-slide https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44218/set-image-to-full-all-available-space-in-beamer-without-overlapping-other-eleme

Answer (score 3):

The `\textheight` of a `beamer` frame *includes the title*, so you likely want something like

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}%{Title}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red] (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,\textheight);
\draw[blue] (0,\textheight) -- (\textwidth,0)
            (0,0) -- (\textwidth, \textheight);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

You might also consider using a `plain` frame and the `\paperheight`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do want a title on my slide. And I want to know the space/height I have remaining for content.

Comment: Joseph, do you know why the example I gave in the comment above require such a small height for the rectangle to be visible? I tested what beamer said about the height of the beamer frame, and `\textheight` was almost identical to it, but still I needed a rectangle height that is 30% of the text height.