# How to create an overlayarea environment within the available area of the frame?

Tags: beamer, positioning, overlays

I was trying to create an `overlayarea` environment below some bullets to dynamically change pictures as I pass the slides without getting a *wobbling* effect. The problem is that I cannot find a way to measure the available space in the frame in order to create a "perfectly fit" environment. If I succeeded, it would be possible to scale my figures properly in a manner that they wouldn't go off frame (like in the picture below).

[image]

What I would like to do is to create an `overlayarea` that fitted perfectly the space inside the black filled rectangle , so that the image would stay inside of it (the distortion of the image is not a problem). The code I used to produce this effect is down below.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\begin{document}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\section{Le sommeil}
\subsection{L'importance du sommeil}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{L'impact sur le plan psychologique}
\begin{itemize} 
    \item Apprentissage et capacité de resoudre problèmes.
    \item Difficultés et désordres psychologiques
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Décisions
            \item Contrôler des émotions
            \item Comportements dangereux, dépression et suicide.
        \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
{\centering
    \begin{overlayarea}{0.7\linewidth}{0.4\textheight}      
        %\only<1->{
            {\centering 
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=\textheight]{imagens/sleep_rem}
            }
        %}
        %\only<2>{
            {\centering 
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=\textheight, keepaspectratio]{imagens/decision}
            }
        %}
    \end{overlayarea}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance for your help! Sorry for any formatting/posting mistake.

Comment: Welcome! I guarantee you didn't use just that code to produce that image. Please can you edit to make your example compilable? That's miles more useful than a fragment.

Comment: Have you considered `overprint`?

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: Thank you both for the tips about the MWE, I'll edit the post asap :)

Comment: And I haven't tried `overprint` @cfr because I heard that `overlayarea` was more flexible, but I will give it a try. Thank you!

Comment: @EmanoelCosta Have a loo at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262815/automatically-fit-the-graphics-in-the-remaining-space-of-a-beamer-slide

Comment: It is more flexible, but less automatic.

Comment: Thank you @samcarter for the tip on [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262815/automatically-fit-the-graphics-in-the-remaining-space-of-a-beamer-slide]. It solved my problem. I didn't use the man's code, but I used part of it to solve my problem.