# Perfectly scale figure to the rest of a page

Tags: beamer, floats, scaling

I want a figure to fit perfectly inside a slide in beamer. This means that it should scale to the smallest dimension between width and height, maintaining proportions, and allowing space to the rest of the content of the slide.

I wrote my following example using code from https://blogs.gnome.org/muelli/2011/04/perfectly-scale-an-image-to-the-rest-of-a-page-with-latex/

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{calc}
%code from https://blogs.gnome.org/muelli/2011/04/perfectly-scale-an-image-to-the-rest-of-a-page-with-latex/
\newlength{\textundbildtextheight}
\newcommand{\textundbild}[2]{
\settototalheight\textundbildtextheight{\vbox{#1}}
#1
\vfill
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio=true,height=\textheight-\the\textundbildtextheight]{#2}
\end{center}
\vfill                                                                                                                                            
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
  \textundbild{description}{fig.png}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However, using this way, the figure still does not fit perfectly. 
See that the figure overlaps the navigation bar on the bottom of the page.

[image]

How do I automatically scale a figure so it respects the content of the frame?

Comment: [Automatically fit the graphics in the remaining space of a Beamer slide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/262815/134144) could be related.

Comment: yes, it's related... I don't know what to do following stack exchange's etiquette. Should I delete my question?

Comment: @MarcKees Do not delete, the question should be closed as duplicate, but kept as a reference, as far as I understand.